# String Concatenation in EL

Tags: java, string, jsp, jstl, el

I would like to concatenate a string within a ternary operator in EL(Expression Language).

Suppose there is a variable named value. If it's empty, I want to use some default text. Otherwise, I need to append it with some static text.

```
${(empty value)? "none" : value + " enabled"}
```

This will not compile however. What would be a correct way to write this? Or is this even possible?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This answer is obsolete. Technology has moved on. Unless you're working with legacy systems see [Joel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549723/304).

---

There is no string concatenation operator in EL. If you don't need the concatenated string to pass into some other operation, just put these expressions next to each other:

```
${value}${(empty value)? 'none' : ' enabled'}
```

Answer (score 109):

With EL 2 you can do the following:

```
#{'this'.concat(' is').concat(' a').concat(' test!')}
```

Comment: `${'this'.concat(' is').concat(' a').concat(' test!')}` would be the normal form.

Comment: Does this work with non-string types, e.g. `${'I am'.concat(' number ').concat(1).concat('!')}`?

Comment: @MartinCarney concat() does only support string arguments

Comment: You need EL 2.2 to call non-getter method (see [How can I check what version of EL is server using](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237216/4944847))

Comment: @Joel doesn't Java coerce the (non-String) argument of `String.concat()` to String automatically calling its `toString()` method?

Comment: @Mindwin I haven't used EL for a while, but with normal Java definitely not. If it's a non-null object, you could call toString() on it though.

Comment: @joel EL coerces the argument before submitting to backing Java code.

Answer (score 48):

If you're already on EL 3.0 (Java EE 7; WildFly, Tomcat 8, GlassFish 4, etc), then you could use the new `+=` operator for this:

```html
<c:out value="${empty value ? 'none' : value += ' enabled'}" />
```

If you're however not on EL 3.0 yet, and the `value` is a genuine `java.lang.String` instance (and thus not e.g. `java.lang.Long`), then use EL 2.2 (Java EE 7; JBoss AS 6/7, Tomcat 7, GlassFish 3, etc) capability of invoking direct methods with arguments, which you then apply on `String#concat()`:

```html
<c:out value="${empty value ? 'none' : value.concat(' enabled')}" />
```

Or if you're even not on EL 2.2 yet, then use JSTL `<c:set>` to create a new EL variable with the concatenated values just inlined in value:

```html
<c:set var="enabled" value="${value} enabled" />
<c:out value="${empty value ? 'none' : enabled}" />
```

Comment: The `+=` method above by far is the most correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

Since Expression Language 3.0, it is valid to use += operator for string concatenation.

```
${(empty value)? "none" : value += " enabled"}  // valid as of EL 3.0
```

Quoting [EL 3.0 Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr341/index.html).

> **String Concatenation Operator**
>
> To evaluate
>
> ```
> A += B
> ```
>
> - Coerce A and B to String.
> - Return the concatenated string of A and B.

Answer (score 1):

[Mc Dowell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642655/725306) is right. I just want to add an improvement if in case you may need to return the variable's value as:

```
${ empty variable ? '<variable is empty>' : variable }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.The +(operator) has not effect to that in using EL.
2.so this is the way,to use that

```
<c:set var="enabled" value="${value} enabled" />


<c:out value="${empty value ? 'none' : enabled}" />
```

is this helpful to You ?

Comment: indent four spaces for code blocks and use the backtick character to escape angle-brackets. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: The exact same solution as BalusC, but a day later? Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

it also can be a great idea using concat for EL + MAP + JSON problem like in this example :

#{myMap[''.concat(myid)].content}