# Create dynamic variable name in jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

My hashmap is in application scope.I have 3 hashmaps mapEnglish, mapSpanish, mapHindi.
The language parameter is available in my session and it is English, or Hindi or Spanish.I can access it like : ${language}

Now I want to create the hashmap name dynamically based on the language parameter.So for example if ${language} is English the map name should be mapEnglish.
How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
<c:forEach items="${applicationScope.map${language}}" var="orderedCityMap">
</c:forEach>
```

But it does not work.Could anyone suggest???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot nest EL expressions to achieve what you need. Have a look at this question [How to nest an EL expression in another EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592614/how-to-nest-an-el-expression-in-another-el-expression)

If  the number of hashmap's you are accessing are limited, then you may look at using the `<c:choose>` tag. Here is one example.

```
Map<String, Integer> englishHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> spanishHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Map<String, Integer> hindiHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

englishHashMap.put("english", 1);
englishHashMap.put("hindi", 2);
englishHashMap.put("telugu", 3);

spanishHashMap.put("english1", 1);
spanishHashMap.put("hindi1", 2);
spanishHashMap.put("telugu1", 3);

hindiHashMap.put("english2", 1);
hindiHashMap.put("hindi2", 2);
hindiHashMap.put("telugu2", 3);

String language = "English";

context.setAttribute("mapEnglish", englishHashMap);
context.setAttribute("mapSpanish", spanishHashMap);
context.setAttribute("mapHindi", hindiHashMap);
context.setAttribute("language", language);
```

You can access the hashmap in the jsp page like below

```
<c:set var="language" value="${applicationScope.language}"/>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${language == 'English'}">
        <c:set var="requiredMap" value="${mapEnglish}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${language == 'Spanish'}">
        <c:out value="Spanish"/>
        <c:set var="requiredMap" value="${mapSpanish}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:out value="Hindi"/>
        <c:set var="requiredMap" value="${mapHindi}"/>
    </c:otherwise>  
</c:choose>
<c:forEach items="${requiredMap}" var="orderedCityMap">
    Key:<c:out value="${orderedCityMap.key}"/>,
    Value:<c:out value="${orderedCityMap.value}"/><br>
</c:forEach>
```

The output is :

```
Key:telugu, Value:3
Key:hindi, Value:2
Key:english, Value:1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this, especially if it's only limited to a handful of languages:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${language == 'English'}>
    <c:set var="map" value="${applicationScope.mapEnglish}"/>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${language == 'Hindi'}>
    <c:set var="map" value="${applicationScope.mapHindi}"/>
</c:when>
<c:when test="${language == 'Spanish'}>
    <c:set var="map" value="${applicationScope.mapSpanish}"/>
</c:when>
</c:choose>

<c:forEach items="${map}" var="orderedCityMap">
...
</c:forEach>
```