# how to put ${status.index} inside another el? like this "${errors.hasFieldErrors('list[ ${status.index} ].count') }"

Tags: jsp, el

```
<c:forEach items="${list.productList}" var="dto" varStatus="status">
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
.......
.......
</c:forEach>

<spring:hasBindErrors name="productDto">
<c:if test="${errors.hasFieldErrors('productList[ *INDEX* ].count') }">
ERROR MESSAGE
</c:if>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

I would like to print the error message if the errors exist.
However, there already exist double and single quotations and EL tag. So, putting index doesn't work well. 
I tried 
<c:if test="${errors.hasFieldErrors('productList[ **${status.index}** ].count') }">, 
<c:if test="${errors.hasFieldErrors('productList[ **[status.index]** ].count') }"> 
, but still doesn't work. Please have a look at this. Thank you.

Comment: Use `${errors.hasFieldErrors(productList[status.index].count)}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to nest an EL expression in another EL expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592614/how-to-nest-an-el-expression-in-another-el-expression)

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thank you for your comment. Based on that, I tried some other options. This way worked! `<c:set var="productList" value="productList[${status.index}].count" /> `  `<c:if test="${errors.hasFieldErrors(productList)}">` Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use a tick ( ` ) instead of opening and closing quotes

```
`${.......} some other stuff`;
```

Comment: Do you mean the tick is needed in front of ${errors.hasFieldErrors...? I don't know well where the tick is needed.

Comment: This is not JavaScript it's EL