# Can't we give two values for one lable in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have one label field which is license and I want give two license numbers for this..how to give two values here. I have one properties file (manageprofile) and one java class (manageprofiledatabean) which contains the license values

```
<h:outputLabel value="#('label.manageprofile.license')"/>

    <h:outputText value="#{manageProfileDataBean.license}"  />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;

    <h:outputText escape="false" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;"></h:outputText>
```

Comment: Trying to clarify things: `manageprofile` is a [Resource Bundle](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/)? And what's the name of the second license value field?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, `h:outputLabel` is meant to be used for labelling input controls - it renders as the html `<label>` tag(e.g.)

```
<h:outputLabel for="myname" value="#{bean.labelValue}" />
<h:inputText id="myname" value="#{bean.name} />
```

If you need to specify multiple values in expression language you can do so like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.property1 bean.property2}"/>
```

so I guess in your case you would write it as

```
<h:outputText value="#{'label.manageprofile.license' manageProfileDataBean.license}" />
```

Finally, you don't need to use an h:outputText if you're not referenceing any propery so the last pair of nbsp characters don;t need to be in in outputText tag at all.

Comment: Your EL isn't valid. There's no `#()`, and your property access probably should be `#{bean.property1} #{bean.property2}`.

Comment: nope, you don't have to use expressions for value, plain text is just fine - unusual, but fine - try it yourslf. The second point is also incorrect you can concatebtate properties inside the #{} syntax.

Comment: We *are* talking about JSR-245 EL? Maybe you intended to write `bean.property1 + bean.property2`? And I'm aware of composite expressions, it's just that `#()` or `#(}` aren't legal EL expressions.

Comment: Fixed the ( typo and updated the label example to be more realistic. You can use the + operator but it isn't necessary! I tested on tomcat 7 with standard reference jsf implementation and it works

Comment: Actually, [you can't in <EL-3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3640254/785663). `+` is an arithmetic operator, you'd need to use `bean.property1.concat(bean.property2)` for strings. No idea why a space works for you. Maybe someone can shed light on that, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Concat both values in one string variable of manageProfileDataBean and then set it in

```
public class ManageProfileDataBean{

private String license = "";
private String val1 = "val1":
private String val2 = "val2";

public ManageProfileDataBean(){
      license = val1+val2;
}

//setter getter

}
```