# How to access iterator variable in Struts tag?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I'm looping over a list and want to access the value to create a text input field. Unfortunatley I'm failing to access the loop variable inside the `<s:textfield>` tag

This is what I tried:

```
  <s:iterator var="tag" value="searchTagList">
    <s:property value="#tag"/>
    <s:textfield key="searchResults.#tag" name="#tag" value="#tag" />
  </s:iterator>
```

The `<s:property value="#tag"/>` is evaluated correctly and shows the loop variable. But the `#tag` in the `<s:textfield>` is never evaluated.

I also tried to put `<s:property value="#tag"/>` instead of `#tag` without success.

Comment: Can you please try   value="%{#tag}"

Comment: Thanks, this works for the `name` nand `value` tags. But `searchResults.%{#tag}` is not resolved.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640254/string-concatenation-in-el might help.

Comment: This post address JSP EL, struts is using OGNL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag's `key` attribute used instead of three ones `name`,`value`,`label`. As far as two of them you have already defined, you can change

```
<s:textfield label="%{getText('searchResults.'+#tag)}" name="%{#tag}" />
```

The value is retrieved by the `name` attribute. You should provide a getter for the name evaluated in the name attribute. Note, `getText()` is available if your action extends `ActionSupport`. And you have to force name evaluation in the name tag.