# Evaluate an expression in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have the following code in my JSP:

```
<c:set var="myBoolean" value="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"/>
<c:out value="${myBoolean}"/>
<c:out value="${requestScope[myBoolean]}"/>
```

In item i have several booleans lockCode1, lockCode2, .... so I use the firs line of code to get the string "item.lockCode1", "item.lockCode2". 
This expression (item.lock${myappli.code.value()}) works fine. I use it to create my checkboxes:

```
<form:checkbox  path="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"  value="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"                                                       />
```

Now what i would like is to evaluate the value of "item.lockCode1", "item.lockCode2", .... so that i get the value of the boolean lockCodeX.

When i write

```
<c:out value="${myBoolean}"/>
```

it displays:
item.lockCodeX

I found the third line on stackoverflow :

```
<c:out value="${requestScope[myBoolean]}"/>
```

which i hoped would evaluate "item.lockCodeX" and give me 'true' or 'false', that is its value. But it doesnt work. How could i get my expression "item.lockCodeX" to be evaluated to true/false?

Thanks,
E.

PS:
My ultimate goal is that I want to (des)activate the checkbox according to the value of the boolean item.lockCodeX.
So I thought about something like that:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="here evaluate my expression to true/false">
        <form:checkbox          path="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"
value="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}" disabled="false"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <form:checkbox          path="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"
value="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}" disabled="true"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

PS2: I cant use a map, the code is like that, I cant change it.

PS3:
 I have tried to write:

```
 <c:when test="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}">
```

and
 `<c:when test="${item.lock${myappli.code.value()}}">` 
but it doesnt work.

PS4:
Here is the relevant lines of the object item:

```
public class Lot extends BaseEntite {

...

    private Boolean lockBEL;

    private Boolean lockPAR

    private Boolean lockCIA;

    private Boolean lockAFA;

    private Boolean lockLO;
...
```

In my Controller I get the object from a webservice and I put it in my ModelAttribute searchForm:

```
searchMetier.getResultsSearch(context, this.formToDemand(searchForm));
```

Comment: From your code, i don't get what type is variables isLockCode1 and lockCode? Is item a collection which contain objects lockCode1, lockCode2, ..., and these objects have boolean fields isLockCode1 or isLockCode2?

Comment: @drgPP Item is an object that contains booleans such as lockCode1, item.lockCode2, etc...

Comment: Can you post the code how you create item object?, and it's class?

Comment: @drgPP I edited my original question to put the info you want at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

What i see from your code is that the line

`<c:set var="myBoolean" value="item.lock${myappli.code.value()}"/>`
gives to you a `String` value, so you don't really have access to it's `Boolean` fields. To do so, you need to retrieve in value item `Object` itself, so you can get the `Boolean` value as `item.lockBEL.value()`.

I would try as follows:

```
<c:set var="myItem" value="${item}">

<c:set var="myBoolean" value="${myItem.lockBEL.value()}"
```

If you want to get lock+(BEL or PAR or ...) when you should use some techniques that EL provides like concatination, some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640254/string-concatenation-in-el). The problem is i'm not very familiar with EL but as i see nobody replies i decided to give a try.

PS: i see that you set your fields as private, so you should provide some public getters to have access to them, may be something like this would work: `{$myItem.getLockBEL().value()}`